# Как сделать иконку внутри шестигранной фигуры, чтобы при наведении шестигранник заливался цветом, а иконка меняла цвет с черного на белый?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, img

Как сделать иконку внутри шестигранной фигуры, чтобы при наведении шестигранник заливался цветом, а иконка меняла цвет с черного на белый?

Comment: вы хотя бы иллюстрацию добавьте к своему вопросу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот с использованием `svg` и `fontawesome`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<svg width="100" height="100">

<polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"/>
<text x="50"y="55">&#xf099</text>

<style>
  polygon {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2.2px;
    transition: 300ms;
  }

  text{
    stroke: transparent;
    fill: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: FontAwesome; 
    dominant-baseline: middle;
    text-anchor: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 300ms;
  }
  
  svg{
    transition:300ms;
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  
  svg:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }

  svg:hover polygon {
    fill: rgba(75,175,222,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke-width: 0px;
  }

  svg:hover text {
    stroke-width: 1.4px;
    fill: snow;
    stroke: black;
  }
</style>

</svg>
```

PS: чтобы вставить `fa` иконку в `svg` обратный слэш необходимо заменить на `&#x`